# Add CSS bounce animation to a div on click only for once

Tags: javascript, css

I have a CSS map pin which has some CSS3 animations, here it is:'

https://jsfiddle.net/xg7xfzeq/

```
body {
  background: #e6e6e6;
}

.pin {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 0;
  background: #00cae9;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin: -20px 0 0 -20px;
}
.pin:after {
  content: "";
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  margin: 8px 0 0 8px;
  background: #e6e6e6;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.bounce {
  animation-name: bounce;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

.pulse {
  background: #d6d4d4;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin: 11px 0px 0px -12px;
  transform: rotateX(55deg);
  z-index: -2;
}
.pulse:after {
  content: "";
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: -13px 0 0 -13px;
  animation: pulsate 1s ease-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  opacity: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 2px #00cae9;
  animation-delay: 1.1s;
}

@keyframes pulsate {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.1, 0.1);
    opacity: 0;
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes bounce {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-2000px) rotate(-45deg);
  }

  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(30px) rotate(-45deg);
  }

  80% {
    transform: translateY(-10px) rotate(-45deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translateY(0) rotate(-45deg);
  }
}
.myBounceDiv { 
        -moz-animation:bounce .40s linear;  
        -webkit-animation:bounce .40s linear; 
} 

@-moz-keyframes bounce {


 0%{ -moz-transform:scale(0); opacity:0;}
        50%{ -moz-transform:scale(1.3); opacity:0.4; }
        75%{ -moz-transform:scale(0.9); opacity:0.7;}
        100%{ -moz-transform:scale(1); opacity:1;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
        0%{ -webkit-transform:scale(0); opacity:0;}
        50%{ -webkit-transform:scale(1.3); opacity:0.4;}
        75%{ -webkit-transform:scale(0.9); opacity:0.7;}
        100%{ -webkit-transform:scale(1); opacity:1;}
}
```

and its HTML

```
<div class='myBounceDiv'>
<div class='pin bounce'></div>
<div class='pulse'></div>
</div>
```

Well, I want to add bounce css3 animation on click, I have found some solutions for it such as changing CSS style when we click on its div using javascript. 
While it is possible but when I change its CSS class it will start to bounce every forever. How can make it animate only once? One way could be triggering a timer and after 1000 ms changing its css class into its first class, but there is another problem, my div's class has another animation (when it first appears in page, it drops from top to bottom) so if I change its css class to bouncing animation and again change it to its original the appearance animation trigers again and it is not what I need. 
Is there any way to achieve what I need using pure javascript and CSS? In fact, i need to make something like this
http://dynamicsjs.com/examples/pin.html
but its animation appears on click using CSS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I understood you mean this:

- In the **first version** pulse effect and bounce effect run only clicking once
- In the **second version** pulse effect run always like present version but bounce effect run only clicking once

**First version**

```js
element = document.getElementById("marker");

element.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault;
  
  // -> removing the class
  element.classList.remove("bounce");
  
  // -> triggering reflow /* The actual magic */
  // without this it wouldn't work. Try uncommenting the line and the transition won't be retriggered.
  element.offsetWidth = element.offsetWidth;
  
  // -> and re-adding the class
  element.classList.add("bounce");
}, false);
```

```css
body {
  background: #e6e6e6;
}

.pin {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 0;
  background: #00cae9;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin: -20px 0 0 -20px;
}
.pin:after {
  content: "";
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  margin: 8px 0 0 8px;
  background: #e6e6e6;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.bounce {
  animation-name: bounce;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-duration: 0.9s;
}

.pulse {
  background: #d6d4d4;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin: 11px 0px 0px -12px;
  transform: rotateX(55deg);
  z-index: -2;
}
.bounce+.pulse:after {
  content: "";
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: -13px 0 0 -13px;
  animation: pulsate 1s ease-out;
  opacity: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 2px #00cae9;
  animation-delay: 0.1s;  
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

@keyframes pulsate {
  0%, 100% {
    transform: scale(0.1, 0.1);
    opacity: 0;
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes bounce {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-1000px) rotate(-45deg);
  }

  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(30px) rotate(-45deg);
  }

  80% {
    transform: translateY(-10px) rotate(-45deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translateY(0) rotate(-45deg);
  }
}
.myBounceDiv { 
        -moz-animation:bounce .40s linear;  
        -webkit-animation:bounce .40s linear; 
} 

@-moz-keyframes bounce {
        0%{ -moz-transform:scale(0); opacity:0;}
        50%{ -moz-transform:scale(1.3); opacity:0.4; }
        75%{ -moz-transform:scale(0.9); opacity:0.7;}
        100%{ -moz-transform:scale(1); opacity:1;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
        0%{ -webkit-transform:scale(0); opacity:0;}
        50%{ -webkit-transform:scale(1.3); opacity:0.4;}
        75%{ -webkit-transform:scale(0.9); opacity:0.7;}
        100%{ -webkit-transform:scale(1); opacity:1;}
}
```

```html
<div class='myBounceDiv'>
<div id="marker" class='pin'></div>
<div class='pulse'></div>
</div>
```

**Second version**

```js
/*
  Reference: https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/
*/

element = document.getElementById("marker");

element.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault;
  
  // -> removing the class
  element.classList.remove("bounce");
  
  // -> triggering reflow /* The actual magic */
  // without this it wouldn't work. Try uncommenting the line and the transition won't be retriggered.
  element.offsetWidth = element.offsetWidth;
  
  // -> and re-adding the class
  element.classList.add("bounce");
}, false);
```

```css
body {
  background: #e6e6e6;
}

.pin {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 0;
  background: #00cae9;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin: -20px 0 0 -20px;
}
.pin:after {
  content: "";
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  margin: 8px 0 0 8px;
  background: #e6e6e6;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.bounce {
  animation-name: bounce;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-duration: 0.9s;
}

.pulse {
  background: #d6d4d4;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin: 11px 0px 0px -12px;
  transform: rotateX(55deg);
  z-index: -2;
}
.pulse:after {
  content: "";
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: -13px 0 0 -13px;
  animation: pulsate 1s ease-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  opacity: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 2px #00cae9;
  animation-delay: 0.1s;  
}

@keyframes pulsate {
  0%, 100% {
    transform: scale(0.1, 0.1);
    opacity: 0;
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes bounce {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-1000px) rotate(-45deg);
  }

  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(30px) rotate(-45deg);
  }

  80% {
    transform: translateY(-10px) rotate(-45deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translateY(0) rotate(-45deg);
  }
}
.myBounceDiv { 
        -moz-animation:bounce .40s linear;  
        -webkit-animation:bounce .40s linear; 
} 

@-moz-keyframes bounce {
        0%{ -moz-transform:scale(0); opacity:0;}
        50%{ -moz-transform:scale(1.3); opacity:0.4; }
        75%{ -moz-transform:scale(0.9); opacity:0.7;}
        100%{ -moz-transform:scale(1); opacity:1;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
        0%{ -webkit-transform:scale(0); opacity:0;}
        50%{ -webkit-transform:scale(1.3); opacity:0.4;}
        75%{ -webkit-transform:scale(0.9); opacity:0.7;}
        100%{ -webkit-transform:scale(1); opacity:1;}
}
```

```html
<div class='myBounceDiv'>
<div id="marker" class='pin'></div>
<div class='pulse'></div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

```js
/*
  Reference: https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/
*/




element = document.getElementById("marker");


setTimeout(function() {
  element.classList.remove("bounce");
}, 1000);


element.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault;
  
  // -> removing the class
  element.classList.remove("drop");
  
  // -> triggering reflow /* The actual magic */
  // without this it wouldn't work. Try uncommenting the line and the transition won't be retriggered.
  element.offsetWidth = element.offsetWidth;
  
  // -> and re-adding the class
  element.classList.add("drop");
}, false);
```

```css
body {
  background: #e6e6e6;
}

.pin {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 0;
  background: #00cae9;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin: -20px 0 0 -20px;
}
.pin:after {
  content: "";
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  margin: 8px 0 0 8px;
  background: #e6e6e6;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.bounce {
  animation-name: bounce;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-duration: 0.9s;
}

.pulse {
  background: #d6d4d4;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin: 11px 0px 0px -12px;
  transform: rotateX(55deg);
  z-index: -2;
}
.pulse:after {
  content: "";
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: -13px 0 0 -13px;
  animation: pulsate 1s ease-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  opacity: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 2px #00cae9;
  animation-delay: 0.1s;  
}

@keyframes pulsate {
  0%, 100% {
    transform: scale(0.1, 0.1);
    opacity: 0;
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes bounce {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-1000px) rotate(-45deg);
  }

  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(5px) rotate(-45deg);
  }

  80% {
    transform: translateY(-10px) rotate(-45deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translateY(0) rotate(-45deg);
  }
}
.myBounceDiv { 
        -moz-animation:bounce .40s linear;  
        -webkit-animation:bounce .40s linear; 
} 

@-moz-keyframes bounce {
        0%{ -moz-transform:scale(0); opacity:0;}
        50%{ -moz-transform:scale(1.3); opacity:0.4; }
        75%{ -moz-transform:scale(0.9); opacity:0.7;}
        100%{ -moz-transform:scale(1); opacity:1;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
        0%{ -webkit-transform:scale(0); opacity:0;}
        50%{ -webkit-transform:scale(1.3); opacity:0.4;}
        75%{ -webkit-transform:scale(0.9); opacity:0.7;}
        100%{ -webkit-transform:scale(1); opacity:1;}
}



@keyframes drop {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-40px) rotate(-45deg);
  }

  80% {
    transform: translateY(3px) rotate(-45deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translateY(0) rotate(-45deg);
  }
}

.drop {
  animation-name: drop;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class='myBounceDiv'>
<div id="marker" class='pin bounce'></div>
<div class='pulse'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sir @Majid Hojati if my answer solved your problem please don't forget accept it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for your answer, In fact I want pin to drop from top and just bounce when it is clicked on. is it possible?in your examples pin drops each time I click I just want to bounce (jump up and down a little) when I clock on

Comment: Oh I understood. Yes of course it is possible. Let me

Comment: Hi, thanks very much, It seems goldins answer is what I exolauned

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing CSS classes to the bouncing animation and back to the original, you can instead add (on click) and remove (after 1s) classes to either `pin` or `myBounceDiv`. Something to note is that you'll also need to remove the `bounce` class once the animation completes.

It would look something like this:

```
const pinEl = document.querySelector('.pin');

setTimeout(() => pinEl.classList.remove('bounce'), 1000);
function removeMiniBounce() {
    pinEl.classList.remove("miniBounce");
  }
pinEl.onclick = () => {
  pinEl.classList.add("miniBounce");
  setTimeout(removeMiniBounce, 1000);
}
```

And your CSS would be:

```
@keyframes miniBounce {
    0%{ -webkit-transform:translateY(0px) rotate(-45deg);}
    30%{ -webkit-transform:translateY(-20px) rotate(-45deg);}
    60%{ -webkit-transform:translateY(0px) rotate(-45deg);}
    70%{ -webkit-transform:translateY(-5px) rotate(-45deg);}
    100%{ -webkit-transform:translateY(0) rotate(-45deg);}
}

.miniBounce {
  animation: miniBounce 0.4s ease-in-out; 
}
```

Comment: @golins yes thanks this is exactly what I need.Is it possible to achieve an animation like this link using css?http://dynamicsjs.com/examples/pin.html

Comment: You mean the entire animation? It's absolutely possible, as that animation is done with `matrix3d` CSS transformations (presumably generated by `dynamicsjs`). You can implement similar animations with other `transform` value such as scale, rotate, and translate. See how those are used in your example (such as `rotateZ: -45`)